# Calculating total from one list and populating total in column of another list

Tags: workflow

I have an individual systems list, on which are a column of divisions (Parks) and a column of systems (Compliant).

I also have a program-wide system list, that has a column of Compliant systems.

Is there a way to create, on the program-wide list, a column that auto-populates the 'number' of compliant systems from the individual list of systems - based on the Park where they are locate.

Example: individual list may contain 10 line items of systems at 'ACME' park; 7 of those systems are compliant, 3 are not compliant.

The calculated column of the program-wide list, or the workflow, would need to automatically place a '7' in the program-wide list 'Compliant' system column.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are able create relationships between lists by using a combination of unique columns, lookup columns, and relationship enforcement (cascade and restrict delete).

Here is how you would do it:
[How to create count related lookup column in SharePoint custom lists](http://pawansatope.blogspot.com.br/2012/01/how-to-create-count-related-lookup.html)

Comment: The Park list has columns, including Park and Status (automatically updated by calculated columns/workflows), and can read 'Compliant' or 'Noncompliant'. Region-wide list has 2 columns, Park and Status. I want a count of instances of 'Compliance' (only), from 1st list to 2nd list - based on Park. Seems, what's proposed brings total number of status, based on the Park. Is there a way to filter the 1st list Status column so only 'Compliant' status is count, based on park, and migrated to 2nd list?